# Постоянные переменные

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Всем доброго времени суток. Изучаю разработку Android приложений и появился вопрос.

К примеру у меня есть форма авторизации где пользователь вбивает свой логин и пароль.

Я хочу сохранить то что вбил пользователь в переменных. Но мне нужны такие переменные что бы они хранили свое значение на протяжении всего существования приложения либо до тех пор пока пользователь не сменит их значение. Подскажите в какую сторону смотреть ? Может есть у кого пример ??

Comment: Забыл дописать что переменные не должны перетираться после того как пользователь закрыл приложение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для таких целей созданы `SharedPreferences`.

Объявите глобально:

```
SharedPreferences preferences;
```

Определите переменную, которая будет хранить данные приложения в корневой папке приложения в файле `variables.xml`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    preferences = getSharedPreferences("variables", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}
```

Следующий код будет сохранять данные в `preferences`. Нужно создать `Editor` для `preferences`, с помощью которого мы сможем изменять сохранённые данные:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("name","Ivan");
editor.putString("password","123456");
editor.apply();
```

Обращаться к сохранённым в устройстве переменным можно так:

```
String name= preferences.getString("name", "default");
String password= preferences.getString("password", "default");
```

Переменные получат значение `default`, если они ранее не были сохранены в устройстве.

Надеюсь, хорошо объяснил. Если будут вопросы - пишите, не стесняйтесь =)

Comment: Думаю, стоит добавить пару слов о том, что для хранения паролей нужно придумать что-то понадежнее, ибо так пароль, по сути, [открыт всему миру](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233035/best-option-to-store-username-and-password-in-android-app)

Comment: @selya, верно. Дельный совет!

Comment: @EgorRandomize Спасибо большое за понятный пример ! А как тогда хранить лучше пароль в приложении ?? Я со своим маленьким опытом в этой сфере придумал только такой вариант.  А какие есть еще ??

Comment: @alexsis20102, есть разные методы хранения паролей, и у каждого метода свои минусы. Можете взять дайджест (хеш, например `md5`, правда `md5` мало любят в отраслях информационной безопасности) пароля, либо использовать какую-нибудь крипто-библиотеку. А это - повод для создания новой темы по решению вопроса безопасного хранения пароля...

Comment: @EgorRandomize До md5 я еще не добрался )) Но хотел в будущем хранить в такой переменной как описано выше шифрованный пароль. Шифровать с помощью md5 с добавлением соли реверса и все будет ок. Или даже в таком виде нельзя хранить пароль в такой переменной ??

Comment: @alexsis20102, нежелательно =) Лучше воспользоваться советами Руслана Ягупова, он верно мыслит по этому поводу )

Answer (score 4):

Используйте [Android Account Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31915642/android-login-account-authenticator-vs-manual-authentication), [офф.доки](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AbstractAccountAuthenticator.html). [Пример реализации](https://www.pilanites.com/android-account-manager/).
P.S никогда не используйте шары или просто файлы для хранения паролей, токенов или приватных ключей(!!!). У гугла есть люди которые давно многое для нас придумали, используйте.